# Wanted to open app in real device by vs code but got this error.Thanks in advance

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Y3 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader

  > com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.AnnotationReader
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

### **verbose flag**

```
 D:\Apps\quiz_app> flutter run --verbose
[  +25 ms] executing: [D:\Software\Flutter\] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1
--pretty=format:%H
[ +239 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +2 ms] 27321ebbad34b0a3fafe99fac037102196d655ff
[        ] executing: [D:\Software\Flutter\] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent
--long --tags
[ +150 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[   +1 ms] v1.12.13+hotfix.5-0-g27321ebba
[  +27 ms] executing: [D:\Software\Flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[ +108 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +1 ms] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [D:\Software\Flutter\] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +85 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +119 ms] executing: [D:\Software\Flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[ +167 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +1 ms] stable
[ +165 ms] executing: D:\Software\Android Studios\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +66 ms] Exit code 0 from: D:\Software\Android Studios\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[        ] List of devices attached
           50a09aea               device product:onc model:Redmi_Y3 device:onc
           transport_id:13
[  +19 ms] D:\Software\Android Studios\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 50a09aea shell getprop
[ +172 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +22 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[  +18 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[  +17 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.   
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping       
update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping       
update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping      
update.
[  +12 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping
update.
[ +261 ms] Generating
D:\Apps\quiz_app\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +33 ms] ro.hardware = qcom
[  +71 ms] Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Y3 in debug mode...
[  +18 ms] executing: D:\Software\Android Studios\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 50a09aea shell
-x logcat -v time -s flutter
[  +22 ms] executing: D:\Software\Android Studios\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[ +378 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
                    Version 30.0.1-6435776
                    Installed as D:\Software\Android Studios\platform-tools\adb.exe        
[   +6 ms] executing: D:\Software\Android Studios\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[  +62 ms] Building APK
[  +20 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[   +2 ms] gradle.properties already sets `android.enableR8`
[   +4 ms] Using gradle from D:\Apps\quiz_app\android\gradlew.bat.
[  +11 ms] executing: D:\New folder\jre\bin\java -version
[ +288 ms] Exit code 0 from: D:\New folder\jre\bin\java -version
[   +1 ms] openjdk version "1.8.0_242-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b01, mixed mode)
[   +4 ms] executing: [D:\Apps\quiz_app\android\] D:\Apps\quiz_app\android\gradlew.bat     
-Pverbose=true -Ptarget=D:\Apps\quiz_app\lib\main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true        
-Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root -Ptarget-platform=android-arm64 assembleDebug        
[+4064 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +3 ms] * What went wrong:
[   +2 ms] com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader
[  +10 ms] > com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.AnnotationReader
[   +2 ms] * Try:
[   +8 ms] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[   +3 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[  +43 ms] BUILD FAILED in 3s
[ +517 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 5.0s)
[   +7 ms] "flutter run" took 6,528ms.
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:387:7)
#2      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure>
(dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:73:64)
#3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
#4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
#5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
#6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback
(dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
#7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)
#8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524:5)
#9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:32:15)
#10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:290:13)
#11     _DefaultProcessUtils.stream (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart)
#12     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure>
(dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:73:64)
#13     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
#14     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
#15     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
#16     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback
(dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
#17     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)
#18     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524:5)
#19     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:554:7)      
#20     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#21     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#22     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
#23     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)  
#24     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
#25     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
#26     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)        
#27     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:175:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first try uninstalling the previous build of the application. If that doesn't work try running the command:

```
flutter clean
```